# Can NAS appliances be used as external DAS (Direct-attached storage) enclosures with RAID?

Tags: nas

Forgive my probably dim questions but I want some kind of multi drive bay with RAID functionality. I keep hearing Drobo and Synology being mentioned in the same breath (normally with buy Synology as the conclusion).

Am I wrong in thinking they are quite different? One does fancy network stuff + RAID and one just does some proprietary RAID stuff.

Since I have been steered the way of Synology yet don't need any of the networked/server type functions (and crucially, can't store it by the router anyways) - can it be plugged directly into the PC to use the raid capability? Is there a better way?

Comment: What interface would you require to connect to the PC?

Comment: hopefully usb 3 or maybe e-sata

Comment: If you don't want NAS, is there a reason for focusing on NAS devices?  Or do you want the option to NAS down the track?  Synology don't tend to have a direct connection method whereas Drobo do.

Comment: I was advised that Synology was rock solid and Drobo has some issues - on top of the fact that the Drobo solution is proprietary. I guess I just want a RAID device that is direct attached but haven't seen anything like that yet - do they exist?

Comment: Yes, there are many.  QNAP and Netgear spring to mind.

Comment: Thanks for all your comments - I've searched QNAP/Netgear sites and Amazon UK for those products and haven't found a non-networked DAS....

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood - you mean something like this? http://www.promise.com/storage/raid_series.aspx?region=en-global&m=192&rsn1=40&rsn3=28

Comment: yep - that's exactly the sort of thing thanks, strangely pricier than a NAS equivalent...